# How to send web-project to my localserver?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I don't quite understand how to link my web application and server. Tried to use

```js
res.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/index.html'));
```

But it doesn't connect components written in vue.js

Comment: Is this just for development or production?

Comment: for development. 
I built the project using vue build. Now you need the server to pull all files from this folder, not just .html

Comment: For development you can just use `npm run serve` and have Node running independently as the server

Comment: I need to establish interaction with the server. Data exchange

Comment: You mean HTTP requests? For that you can use Axios

Comment: the essence of the task is to write a web application on the view. Which will work as total commander. I don't know what's best to do

Comment: in my understanding the server will send a Json file to the site and receive data about working with it in response

Comment: You can run Vue independently of the backend on the development server using `npm run serve`, then Node as the backend server using something like Nodemon and use Axios to communicate between the two. However, production would need a different config.

Comment: in my understanding the server sends the built web application and deploys it

Comment: In production, yes. It's not nescessary in development

Comment: in any case, I will need it in the future, how do I assign a folder for the server so that it can take all the necessary files from there?

Answer (score 1):

In `vue.config.js` (make one in your client `src` folder if you haven't already), add the target directory for the build:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/server/directory/public")
};
```

Now when you run `npm run build` the static files will be bundled there.

---

Then, all you need to do is point your server to that folder.

If you're using Node/Express as a backend:

```
// Handle production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Static folder
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
}
```

Also, if your Vue app is an SPA, add this inside the `if` block, after `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));`, to handle routing:

```
// Handle SPA
app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
```